# Npgsql syntax error at or near "DISCARD"

Tags: amazon-redshift, npgsql

I'm running a standard query against Redshift, and every other time I run it, I get:

`[ConciergeClientException: We encountered a problem fulfilling your request: 42601: syntax error at or near "DISCARD"]`

I'm opening and closing the connection properly, and the query looks fine. I've queried Redshift's STL_QUERY and the statement looks fine. I turned on logging, and I can't see where this DISCARD command is being sent.

Yet every other query gives me this error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Ngsql 3.2.0, this looks like a duplicate of https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1426. In a nutshell, Npgsql's pooling was changed in 3.2.0 in a way which is incompatible with Reshift.

As a workaround, specify `No Reset On Close` in your connection string. This will be fixed for 3.2.1.